How to apply Frobenius' Method to ODE with multiple simultaneous singularities
I'm trying to analyze the following ODE and get something closed form.
$$
\phi'' + \frac{1}{\left( \ 1+2b\cos (\theta) \ \right)\left( \ 1+b \cos (\theta) \ \right) \sin (\theta)} \phi' + \frac{\left( \ 1+2b\cos (\theta) \ \right) \left( \ 1+b \cos (\theta) \ \right)+2b^2\sin^2 (\theta)}{\left( \ 1+2b\cos (\theta) \ \right)\left( \ 1+b \cos (\theta) \ \right) \sin^2 (\theta)} \phi = 0
$$
Here b is a constant. The only thing I can think to do is to Taylor expand the coefficients , or parts of the coefficients, about the singularity I'm expanding about in order to get a recursion relation. It seems that the solutions are Legendre polynomial-esque upon getting some numerical plots. This seems a bit more obvious when making the substitution $u = \cos (\theta)$ with the way the derivatives transform.
